# Rules for physical appearances based on charisma and race

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I remember reading rules about how to determine physical attractiveness based on charisma and race, but I'm not sure which book. Does anyone remember where this was?

By the way, I'm not talking about rules that had physical attractiveness affect the actual game, it was just a table that used your charisma, race (and I think maybe one or two other factors) to give you a score, which was then matched to a table to define your "attractiveness". This no real affect on your character (I think).

Comment: Physical attractiveness has nothing to do with charisma. Unless you think dragons are super sexy...

Answer (score 6):

I am almost certain that there are no rules for any such thing. Charisma *may* be tied to appearance, but only very loosely; someone with high Charisma is not necessarily attractive in the least, and someone with low Charisma may still be quite superficially pretty. Charisma would be more about how effectively you use your appearance, whatever it is.

Personally, I think this is a very good thing; a character’s appearance shouldn’t, for example, affect how many bonus spells they get as a sorcerer. I strongly dislike any real mechanical effect to appearance (barring specific things like the Nymph’s supernatural Blinding Beauty)

Comment: There is the Book of Erotic Fantasy as a third-party option, though it introduces Appearance as its own ability score.

Answer (score -1):

There was a Comliness score in a 2nd edition supplement - a Dragon magazine perhaps? It was rediculously overpowered from memory.